# How to disable counting affected rows by MV in ClickHouse?

Tags: jpa, clickhouse

When I inserted data into table which is basic for material view, ClickHouse counts this rows.

```
test> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('xxxx', '2022-01-01')
[2024-02-22 21:13:18] 2 rows affected in 4 ms
```

It leads to thourbles with JPA (it checking really affected rows when batching is used):

```
Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 2; expected: 1
```

I inspected JPA code, and this behavior can not be disabled on this side.
Is it possible to disable this behavior on ClickHouse side?

Comment: Found related issue here https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/18237